# Unpublishing page, error com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13

Tags: 2011, publishing

I am unpublishing 1051 pages, all got success message but one has the following error:

> Unable to store item inside current transaction, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unknown entity:

Deployer log says :

```
<Step state="Failed" start="2014-01-13T12:10:50.817+10:00" type="Deployment committing"
      href="simple" end="2014-01-13T12:10:57.887+10:00">
  <RemoteEndpoint windowSize="0" state="Failed" start="2014-01-13T12:10:50.817+10:00" 
                  processor="2536@otwtridonsql01" name="IIS" id="5e50QEKIyw3FuxiDAQw80Q==" 
                  end="2014-01-13T12:10:57.887+10:00" connector="HTTPS">
    <Message>Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, 
      Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-24659-66560, 
      Unable to store item inside current transaction, 
      Unable to remove data entity, 
      Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, 
      Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, 
      Unable to remove data entity, 
      Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, 
      Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, 
      Unable to store item inside current transaction, 
      Unable to remove data entity, 
      Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, 
      Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, 
      Unable to remove data entity, 
      Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, 
      Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, 
      ...[repeat of entire message]...</Message>
  </RemoteEndpoint>
</Step>
```

Comment: Do you have more from the deployer log?

Comment: original question updated with log content.

Comment: Do you have any custom code (Deployer Extension or Storage Extension) in place?

Comment: no ,there is no extension.

Comment: Any follow up or answer to this issue, Shafaqat?

Comment: Well, it is quite old question now, must have been fixed.

Comment: I am getting same error gain.